# Pentaho transformation GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Has someone experiencing this when tried to run Pentaho with large data source?

My Source is from Postgresql-13

Is there a way to make this job to run without an error?

Seems like memory issues?

i read somehwere to change this (?):

```
if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m"
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, you're running out of memory here. The documentation describes how to do this: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/9.1/Setup/Increase_the_PDI_client_memory_limit

Comment: already tried it and still got the same error :(

Comment: maybe just even more memory? It really depends on the amount of data and what exactly you are doing with it. You can process gigabytes of data with minimal memory footprint if you're just passing row after row through a few simple steps, but if you're sorting or grouping in memory, you may need to increase the memory limit until it stops complaining.